# salesforce connector create method - datetime date value correct but time is always 00:00:00.000?

Tags: datetime, mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I'm performing a create on a Salesforce object. The create is successful, but the datetime field never stores the time that I pass. It's always storing with the time: 00:00:00.000.

**For example:** 2016-03-20T00:00:00.000+0000

I'm using the following to create the date object that gets send to Salesforce:

```
#[groovy: Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',(String)payload.'Login_Date_Time__c')]
```

payload.'Login_Date_Time__c' is a database datetime column, so it's formatted as 2016-03-20 00:56:50

If I log the above, the output definitely shows the time:

Sun Mar 20 00:56:50 MST 2016

Any help here would be appreciated!

Comment: are you able to solve this?

Comment: @RalphRimorin I have provided my solution I finally came up with below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing the following:

For any date that I have from the database that is a datetime value, I convert it to a calendar object.  As long as it's in a calendar object when passed to salesforce, it will be accepted.

I wrote the following method and added it to a java bean.  I then pass in the string value of the sql datetime value.

Example of one way I use it:

```
#[app.registry['StringHelper'].dateTimeStrToCalendarObj((String)payload[0].'MaxLastModifiedDate')]
```

The method:

```
public static Calendar dateTimeStrToCalendarObj(String dateTimeString)
{
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    try
    {
        date = formatter.parse(dateTimeString);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Calendar.getInstance();
}
```